# jQuery Mobile; Rails; Google Oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, oauth-2.0

I have a multi-page jQuery mobile site with Google Oauth 2 working almost perfectly.

Basic routes are:

```
get 'auth/google/callback' => 'my_controller#create'
get "my_controller/signout" => "my_controller#destroy" #, via: :delete
get "auth/failure" => "my_controller#failure", as: "auth_failure"
```

This all work's if the sites root is routed thus:

```
root 'my_controller#index'
```

But if I remove this (which I need to), then on "signout" the page does not load. If I inspect  the html it's all there except the `<body>` tag is missing `class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a"`. 
I just get a blank screen. When I reload it it's all working fine. I've spent two days trying all sorts and got no where so any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rob